# Display values that does not end with ".0" Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements, nan

I have a float column that contains `NaN` values and float values. How do i filter out those values that does not end with `.0`?

For example:

```
Col1
0.7
1.0
1.1
9.0
9.5
NaN
```

Desire result will be:

```
Col1
0.7
1.1 
9.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#convert to string and compare last value
print ((df.Col1.astype(str).str[-1] != '0') & (df.Col1.notnull()))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Col1, dtype: bool

print (df[(df.Col1.astype(str).str[-1] != '0') & (df.Col1.notnull())])
   Col1
0   0.7
2   1.1
4   9.5
```

Another solution for comparing converted value to `ìnt`, but first need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = df.Col1.fillna(1)
print (df[s.astype(int) != s])
   Col1
0   0.7
2   1.1
4   9.5
```

**Timings**:

```
#[30000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

def jez2(df):
    s = df.Col1.fillna(1)
    return (df[s.astype(int) != s])

In [179]: %timeit (df[(df.Col1.astype(str).str[-1] != '0') & (df.Col1.notnull())])
10 loops, best of 3: 80.2 ms per loop

In [180]: %timeit (jez2(df))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop

In [181]: %timeit (df[df.Col1 // 1 != df.Col1].dropna())
100 loops, best of 3: 3.04 ms per loop

In [182]: %timeit (df[df['Col1'].mod(1) > 0].dropna())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.58 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

use `//` division

```
df[df.Col1 // 1 != df.Col1].dropna()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use [`mod(1)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mod.html#pandas.Series.mod) to calculate the modulo with 1:

```
In [60]:
df[df['Col1'].mod(1) > 0].dropna()

Out[60]:
   Col1
0   0.7
2   1.1
4   9.5
```

here we see the effect of `mod`, whole numbers become `0` whilst fractional portions will remain:

```
In [62]:
df['Col1'].mod(1)

Out[62]:
0    0.7
1    0.0
2    0.1
3    0.0
4    0.5
5    NaN
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```